# Chess Bitboard Population

Tags: hex, chess, bitboard

In some bitboard chess engines piece bitboards are initialized as follows:

```
white_pawns = 0x000000000000ff00
black_pawns = 0x00ff000000000000
white_knights = 0x000000000000042
black_knights = 0x4200000000000000
white_bishops =0x000000000000024
black_bishops = 0x2400000000000000
white_rooks = 0x000000000000081
black_rooks = 0x8100000000000000
white_queens = 0x0000000000000008
black_queens = 0x0800000000000000
white_king = 0x0000000000000010
black_king = 0x1000000000000000
```

Can someone please explain how these pieces get their respective hexadecimal values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each bit is being used to represent a position on a chess board, which is an 8x8 grid.

Since bits are being used, it's easier if you look at this in binary rather than hex. For instance, let's look at `white_pawns` in binary:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000
```

Now let's divide that up into groups of eight:

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
11111111
00000000
```

Now you can clearly see that black is at the top, white is at the bottom, and the `1`s indicate where white's pawns are at the beginning of the game.

As a second example, let's look at `white_knights`. It's missing one of its `0`s (although it's harmless, it's bad form), so let's add that zero back: `0x00000000000042`, which looks like this in binary:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000010
```

...which, in groups of eight, looks like this:

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
01000010
```

...which is indeed where white's knights would go.

Comment: ohhh I see!!!
Thnx a lot!!